# Windows Phone 8 open new page programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, navigation

I've started WP 8 development recently. I know C# a bit but not much. BTW, I'm trying to open a page pragmatically, but app is crushing.

My code is here

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Dashboard.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

But I'm being confused because it's working when I'm placing the code above within button click event code block.

> ERROR Detail An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in TestProgram.DLL but was not handled in user code
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued.

I need your advice.

EDIT: Code Added

```
Credens MyCred = new Credens();

// Constructor
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if (MyCred.ifExists("api_key"))
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Dashboard.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }

}
```

Comment: When do you call the Navigate-Method?

Comment: Probably too early and therefore the NavigationService is null because it is not initialized yet.

Comment: @venerik That's my point ;)

Comment: After `InitializeComponent();` I was checking if a condition was fulfilled, I was trying to open Dashboard.xaml.

Comment: What do you mean with "After InitializeComponent();"?

Comment: I've added code to show the exact location.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use the `NavigationService` in the constructor. Put your code to the `OnNavigatedTo` event and it will not crash

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (MyCred.ifExists("api_key"))
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Dashboard.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626521%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) step by step ?

You code seem right. As you said, you should have something like this :

```
private void hyperlinkButton1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Dashboard.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Does you page are on the same folder ? Did you check the path ? Does you page exist ? Can you boot in it ? If you add a break point on the NavigationService, where failed it ?

I think this documentation is pretty helpful.

Comment: Answers should not only contain a link (See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `Navigate()` on the `PhoneApplicationPage` `Loaded` or `OnNavigatedTo()` events.